# when attempting to use "URL_FOR" in jinja2 i get an error of 404, am i missing something?

Tags: python, html, jinja2, bson

so im attempting to create an update feature on my MongoDB. The webpage i am creating needs to be fully CRUD operational through the front end. both create and read are complete, but i cant seem to get my update to work. im trying to pull the data from the db and display it on the webpage so that it can be edited through the use of a form. But i keep getting the error of "mongo is not defined"

i have double checked all syntax etc, to my knowledge all my code seems to be correct. however i am using the mongo shell rather than mongo atlas, so im wondering if that could be the cause? - if it is due to using mongo shell instead, how would i write it ?

```py
@app.route('/edit_recipe/<recipe_id>')
def edit_recipe(recipe_id):
    the_recipe = mongo.db.recipes.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(recipe_id)})
    all_categories = mongo.db.categories.find()
    return render_template('editrecipe.html', recipe=the_recipe, categories=all_categories)
```

```
        <li>
            <div class="collapsible-header">
                <div class="col s3">
                    <i class="material-icons">expand_more</i>
                    <a href="{{url_for('edit_recipe', recipe_id=recipe._id)}}"class="waves-effect waves-light btn btn_small">Edit</a>
```

so what i should get is a basic form pre-filled out with the data from the database. instead i get this error message:

"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jakey Poo\PycharmProjects\recipebook\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2328, in **call**
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Jakey Poo\PycharmProjects\recipebook\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2314, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Jakey Poo\PycharmProjects\recipebook\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1760, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Jakey Poo\PycharmProjects\recipebook\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py", line 36, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Jakey Poo\PycharmProjects\recipebook\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2311, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Jakey Poo\PycharmProjects\recipebook\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1834, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Jakey Poo\PycharmProjects\recipebook\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1737, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Jakey Poo\PycharmProjects\recipebook\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py", line 36, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Jakey Poo\PycharmProjects\recipebook\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1832, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Jakey Poo\PycharmProjects\recipebook\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1818, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint
  File "C:\Users\Jakey Poo\PycharmProjects\recipebook\app.py", line 38, in edit_recipe
    the_recipe = mongo.db.recipes.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(recipe_id)})
NameError: name 'mongo' is not defined"

this is my requirements.txt:

```
Click==7.0
dnspython==1.16.0
Flask==1.0.3
Flask-PyMongo==2.3.0
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
pymongo==3.8.0
Werkzeug==0.15.4
```

Comment: Can you show the modules you have imported?

Comment: Click==7.0
dnspython==1.16.0
Flask==1.0.3
Flask-PyMongo==2.3.0
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
pymongo==3.8.0
Werkzeug==0.15.4
@Tobin

Comment: I especially need to see how you import these modules and how you initialized them. I think the error comes from a bad initialization of the `Flask-PyMongo` module. And also why did you import both the `Flask-PyMongo` and `pymongo` module? Basically they do the same thing; so you can use one or the other but not both ... unless you have specific needs.